# how to combine 2 tables to 1 table in sqlCE?

Tags: sql-server-ce

i have 2 tables that has the same fields

i need to combine 2 tables to 1 table

how to do it in sqlCE ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

Insert all the data from the second in the first one by using a `INSERT ... (SELECT ... )` query. Eventually, if needed, you can add a column to flag the original table the data belongs to. Afterwards, delete the second table.